# (Main entry point class 'com.oneweb.auth.AuthApplication' neither found on classpath )getting error in creating Spring Native Image using GraalVM

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native, gradle-native

I am using graalvm-jdk-17.0.8 and trying to create the native image using GraalVM, while running gradle command "gradle nativecompile". Build is failing.

Error: Main entry point class 'com.oneweb.auth.AuthApplication' neither found on classpath: (All the jar's local path mentioned)

Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$NativeImageError
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.showError(NativeImage.java:1982)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.build(NativeImage.java:1598)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.performBuild(NativeImage.java:1557)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.main(NativeImage.java:1531)

> Task :nativeCompile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

the .exe file should be get from the  gradle nativeCompile Command.